# Cat EOF shell script not working as intended?

Tags: shell, delimiter, ubuntu-16.04, eof, cat

I'm trying to write a shell script that uses cat <> somefilepath/file

to append some information to the end of file.

```
    cat <<EOF>> /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    default_storage_engine = innodb
    innodb_file_per_table = 1
    innodb_file_format = Barracuda
    EOF

    service mysql restart

    echo ""
    echo "" 

    # Create moodle table in mysql 

    echo ------------------------# 
    echo 'Setting up moodle mysql'
    echo ------------------------#
```

weirdly, when running the shell script it seems to ignore the ending EOF and pastes everything seen into the file, breaking stuff. However, in Sublime and in Vi on the server it seems to recognize the EOF correctly, but it breaks when running. How can I get the server to recognize this ending EOF correctly?

I've tried this as well, no luck

```
    cat <<'EOF'>> somefilepath/file 
    blah 
    blah 
    blah 
    EOF
```

Comment: The end of heredoc marker `EOF` should not be indented -- it should start from column 1 and shouldn't have any trailing blanks.  Looks like you have indented it and that's the reason it is being ignored.

Comment: Note that if you *do* want to indent the EOF, you can do so if you use `cat <<- EOF`  Using `<<-` causes all leading indentation to be removed.  (Provided that indentation is reasonable.  eg hard tabs, not spaces)

Comment: Did you put #/bin/sh in the first line of your shell script?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: @codeforester  It's indented for the purposes of having it show up properly here on stack as code. Its not indented whatsoever in the actual file.

Comment: @pelya yes I have

Answer (score 0):

This error started showing up for me when moving some scripts from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04. Maybe some change in the behavior of bash.

After changing the scripts to use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`, "`cat <<EOF>file`" works again.